# Rising Storm/RO2-How do I replace my barrel?

Tags: red-orchestra-2

In Rising Storm/Red Orchestra 2, how do I replace my barrel? I tried pressing the default 6 on my numpad and keyboard, but that didn't work. I rebinded it to an unused key (L) but that didn't do anything. Is it something I need to spawn with?

Comment: Are you using a weapon that allows it? As far as I know you can only do this for the MG, and you need to have fired it for a bit before you can replace it, tho I am not entirely sure about this.

Comment: @Izzo Yes, I was using the Browning for the Americans. The notification popped up along with the button prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your barrel is in needing to a replacement, make sure to deploy the weapon before pressing the replace button.

Answer (score 0):

Only two infantry weapons in the game support barrel swapping. They are the German machine guns, the MG42 and the MG34. To swap the barrel, hit the swap barrel key when you have the weapon mounted on its bipod (so say if youre laid prone) a short animation will play and you will have swapped barrels. Be aware you can only carry one spare at a time, so only swap barrels if your current one is smoking (as it is here when it begins to reduce accuracy of your shots!)